# Can I make a jar file runnable from any directory?

Tags: java, jar, path

I am curious if I can take a `.jar` file and somehow add it to my `classpath` so that I can run it from any directory. For example, let's say I have a `.jar` located at `/home/setup/someJar.jar`. Is there a way I can run this from another directory (preferably any) so that I do not have to navigate back to `/home/setup/` whenever I want to run it?

I tried adding the path to my `.bash_profile` file by adding `:/home/setup` to the `PATH=` line, but didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, i'll look into the reccomendations and see what works best for me. I was not aware of the 'alias' functionality at all. And Since I forgot to explicitly mention it earlier, this is for a linux based system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you probably want an 'alias'.

http://www.linfo.org/alias.html

```
alias myJarShortcut="java -jar /direct/path/to/nameOfYourJar.jar"
```

Add this to your .bash_profile and it will be available every time you boot up.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible but not so easy. you have 3 possiblities

1. Make an alias or symbolic link ([create symbolic link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-creating-symbolic-link-ln-command/))
2. Start it as deamon
3. start it as service ([create service](http://www.ralfebert.de/archive/java/debian_daemon/))

after ready the information above

you can start it like this

```
service [yourservice] start|stop|restart
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a bash script that execute your .jar file in the directory of your choice, with of course the right path to your .jar file.

Comment: I didn't try but something like this should works : `java -jar "C:\your\path\yourfile.jar"`

Comment: Looks like he might not be using windows.